# What are the ID EEPROM pins and what can they be used for?

Tags: gpio

I understand that it's a type of ROM, but is there more to it? How can it be used for?

Answer (score 8):

EEPROMS (Electrically Erasable Programmable Read-Only Memory) are a type of non-volatile memory (they maintain the info even when not powered. You can read more about EEPROMS on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EEPROM).

They are used by Pi HATS (Hardware Attached on Top) EEPROM. Per the Raspberry Pi Foundation's blog.

> The EEPROM holds the board manufacturer information, GPIO setup and a
>   thing called a ‘device tree‘ fragment – basically a description of the
>   attached hardware that allows Linux to automatically load the required
>   drivers.

They should not be used for anything but communicating with the HAT's EEPROM.

The blog post announcing HATs can be found [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/introducing-raspberry-pi-hats/), and the HAT spec can be found [here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/hats).

Comment: Using GPIO 0/1 on a Pi3 (ID_SD/ID_SC) is pretty much a no no because that bus is also used to control internal GPIO.  On earlier Pi models the bus may be used as a normal I2C bus if a HAT isn't being used.

Comment: @joan I have also read that the Pi3 has a port expander, and it seems reasonable that this would be I²C but the pins seem to be in input mode. Are you aware of any documentation of the use?

Comment: @Milliways I vaguely remember reading a post where someone mentioned the model number and I do remember a post where someone had communicated with the device to switch one of the Pi3 LEDs.  They had put up github code which I haven't tried.  The posts were on the raspberrypi.org forums.  I'll have a look later and post a link if I can find the information.

Comment: @Milliways Have a look at https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=72&t=139753 which shows (indirectly via a link) how to control the activity LED on the Pi3.  The best search string seems to be "port expander pi3".

Comment: Actually @joan You can use GPIO 0 & 1 with very little work. For proof of this look at the **Official** Dots board.

Comment: @RyanWalmsley On a Pi3?  The last time I checked there was regular GPU traffic on the I2C bus 0.

Comment: @RyanWalmsley The *Official* Dots board test script only tests for using these as inputs, not outputs