# Can I use ID_SD and ID_SC pins (GPIO 0 and GPIO 1) for general purpose?

Tags: gpio, i2c

I need to use the ID_SD and ID_SC pins for a ultrasonic sensor. Is this possible?

I am already using SDA and SCL for i2c communication so disabling the i2c bus in raspi-config is not an option.

[This stackexchange post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/50348/what-are-the-id-eeprom-pins-and-what-can-they-be-used-for) sheds some light on it but seems to suggest it might be possible. Does anyone have any input on this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware you will be fine provided

1. You are not using a HAT which is configured via ID_SD and ID_SC.
2. You are not using a Pi3 or if you are using a Pi3 you will not be using the ID_SD or ID_SC GPIO in I2C mode.

The Pi3 uses I2C bus 0 for internal purposes.  Setting the ID_SD and ID_SC GPIO as I2C will confuse I2C bus 0.

Comment: Pins 27/28 are configured as Input after boot. I have seen instructions for setting them as I²C (but have not tested this). They are certainly NOT configured as I²C in normal use, so I see no evidence they cannot be used as normal.

Comment: @joan I **am** using it with a Pi 3. Looks like I'm out of luck.

Comment: @Milliways I think they're set as i2c if the i2c bus is enabled in raspi-config.

Comment: @joan Is it possible to switch my SDA and SCL to ID_SD and ID_SC respectively and use them as my i2c connections? Or is i2c bus 0 for Pi3 absolutely out of the question?

Comment: @kimuohs Not on a Pi3.  Using I2C bus 0 is a no no.  However perhaps Milliways is correct, in which case just try using 27/28 as normal GPIO and see if the sonar ranger works.

Comment: @joan it doesn't work.

Comment: @kimuohs I have just connected a sonar ranger to GPIO 0/1 (trigger/echo) with power from 5V and it works on my Pi3.  I get good readings.  Perhaps try again.  I will need to amend my answer after some more tests.

Comment: @Milliways I think you are correct.  I have just used the pins for a sonar ranger.  I think the only restriction is you don't try to use them as an I2C bus on the Pi3.

Comment: @joan Was your I2C bus enabled or disabled in raspi-config?

Comment: @kimuohs I2C bus 1 was enabled, bus 0 wasn't.

Comment: What about Compute Module?  It is not mentioned anywhere to not use GPIO 0,1

Comment: It is written ALL pins can be used as GPIO's when not using alternate functions