# What can I connect in ID_SD and ID_SC pins?

Tags: gpio, i2c

About ID_SD and ID:SC pins...

There is only possible to attach PI-HATS?

Or can I attach just an EEPROM like FM24C08B?

I know [a similar question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/50348/5538) has been asked before.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use GPIO 0/1 as an I2C bus **on the Pi3**.  On the Pi3 I2C bus 0 is used internally.

You can use GPIO 0/1 as ordinary inputs and outputs on the Pi3.

There are no restrictions on earlier Pi models, you can use GPIO 0/1 as ordinary GPIO or as an I2C bus.

This assumes that you do not have a HAT fitted which is using GPIO 0/1 for its own purposes.