# CODEC I2S: Using SGTL5000 in a custom board

Tags: i2c, driver, i2s

I am using this board and this works:

https://fe-pi.com/products/fe-pi-audio-z-v2

Now, I wanted to integrate an SGTL5000 (the above board's CODEC) in a custom board. I designed it and I already have it with me, a local store made it for me and soddered the components.

I suppose the next step would be to just record as I do with the above board:

```
    sudo arecord -r 44100 -f S32_LE test.wav
```

and with the FE-PI 2 board it works ok, with mine I only record noise.

Doesn't the kernel driver take care of everything such as I2C configuration? I double checked the power voltages between the boards and it is relatively the same, give or take 50-100mV, and also the oscillator.

Basically the question is: when using a driver for an I2S CODEC, does the driver take care of the I2C configuration or does the chip need to be "flashed" one time first or whatever?

EDIT: Something is wrong, when I measure the MIC_BIAS voltage on the chip of the working board it gives 2.54V, and when measuring the same pin on my board it only gives 1.49V. I tried setting the voltage manually using a python program but the chip address appears to be locked by the driver. I'm now studying how drivers work so I can get a better understanding on what is happening.

EDIT2: Found the problem, the bias resistor and the cap that is between the MIC_BIAS pin and ground were switched in production, that was the problem. I have to learn how to silkscreen better on Eagle...

Comment: Boards which cover the GPIOs maybe exploiting the [EEPROM ID pins](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/50348/5538) (physically 27 & 28) to load a kernel driver via a device tree overlay.

Comment: This one doesn't. From the board's website: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6Iw7GrAjGT_NWdJV2VaM2NrUWs/view mine is basically a copy of the circuit with more stuff on the board for other systems. I'm only testing one at a time though... I don't expect ghostly EMF interference from other systems :(